# Successive differences of elements in a list with step s apart

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of elements

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, ...}
```

I am trying to get successive differences with step s apart. For example, for $s=3$, I am trying to get `{-a + d, -d + g, -g + j, ...}`.

I started with `diff = Differences[list, 1, 3]` which gives `{-a + d, -b + e, -c + f, -d + g, -e + h, -f + i, -g + j, -h + k, -i + l}`. Then I apply `Take[diff, {1, -1, 3}]` which gives me my desired values.

Is there any way to optimise this code for larger lists?

Thanks

Comment: I think `Differences@list[[;; ;; 3]]` is what you want.

Comment: @yode Thank you

Comment: @yode, that's going to be hard to outdo, so I think you can post that as an answer. :)

Comment: @J.M. Done..  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't sure the OP appreciate this result.So I make it as a comment.Since the OP content with it,so I post it as a answer for reader.

```
list = CharacterRange["a", "z"]
```

> {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}

```
Differences@list[[;; ;; 3]]
```

> {-a+d,-d+g,-g+j,-j+m,-m+p,-p+s,-s+v,-v+y}